# Protecting hidden input textboxes

Tags: php, forms, security, input

So sometimes when I pass variables around from page to page, if I want to pass a variable into a form action, I would simply store it in an `<input type="hidden">` element. This generally works well but I realized that someone could easily go into the HTML markup and simply change `hidden` to type text and therefore they could easily edit what is being passed (this can be bad if say they were editing their own profile and I had stored in the hidden input field their ProfileID and they changed it to someone else's)

I was wondering if there is a best practice to resolving this issue? I talked to some coworkers and they said to put checks on the server when they submit the form to make sure they aren't passing in the incorrect info. Is the best way of going about it or are there other ways?

Comment: Are `sessions` out of your project scope ?

Comment: you could encode/encrypt the value

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Well we do use sessions a lot but like I said I store it in the input hidden so it can be passed through the form. I also think there are times we destroy the session... and my coworkers were telling me how session variables can be manipulated as well?

Comment: @Einacio And they could decode/decrypt it.  Don't trust what the user submits without further authentication.

Comment: @Izkata well, if the user can steal the private key used by mcrypt or openssl or the like on the server, then any protection mechanism is useless anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security-wise, you **cannot** trust any information that comes from the client, as you correctly noted. This means that you have to store it server-side when such pages are called.

A common practice is to give each client a session identifier in a cookie and on the server-side, you can relate all sensitive information to that session identifier. The session identifier should be random, because if it was sequential, you could just change its value and hijack someone else's session at random.

There are multiple ways to store information with regards to a session identifier. The most flexible one in PHP, and probably the easiest to implement, is to use built-in session support. PHP handles the session identifier for you and lets you store any serializable object in the `$_SESSION` superglobal. This is an okay-ish solution, as session data is often stored in the temporary folder of your server, and if it's a shared server, chances are other websites on that server could theoretically snoop in and see or even manipulate session data. Of course, if what you're doing is really low-impact, then it's kind of unlikely that someone would go as far as rent the same server just to mess with you. Still, for instance, OAuth providers recommend that you do not store OAuth tokens in `$_SESSION` storage in public environments.

```
<?php
session_start();
// place anything you need to save between pages in $_SESSION
$_SESSION["foo"] = array("bar", "baz");
// until you unset $_SESSION["foo"], it will be available in every page that called
// session_start().
?>
```

It's a good practice to call `session_destroy` when users log out to make sure that their session data doesn't exist for longer than it needs to.

On the other hand, you can also store information in a database, such as MySQL. This is better security-wise as you should run away from any host that doesn't have distinct database users or distinct databases for each server user, and you can be assured that no one else will be able to change (or even just see) the session information. However, this isn't as flexible, as you need a table structure to store anything you want to store.